# Error occurred while installing subclipse in eclipse luna

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, subclipse, eclipse-luna

Subclipse not installed in Eclipse Luna

Version: Luna Release (4.4.0)
Build id: 20140612-0600

Errors occured while installing subclipse from the URL `http://subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.8.x`.

Following are the errors occured

An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=epp.package.jee, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
Artifact not found: http://subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.8.x/plugins/org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.doc_1.3.0.jar.
http://subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.8.x/plugins/org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.doc_1.3.0.jar

Unable to read repository at https://subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.8.x/content.xml.
Unable to read repository at https://subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.8.x/content.xml.
Connection reset

How to resolve this errors.

Comment: Notify team responsible for repository.

Comment: You probably just need to try again.  The repository exists and works.  Was likely a network hiccup.

Comment: @MarkPhippard it is right. It now works fine.